# Format Spring CommandObject variable on the front end

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How do I format a value that is fetched from a command object on front end.

Its an SSN value which comes from the DB without any `"-"` (Hyphens). How do I convert this?

example: Convert `123456789` into `123-45-6789`. Also the in the backing bean this field is an `Int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a custom property editor?
Spring uses custom property editors to format special data, like SSN.

An IntegerPropertyEditor looks like this:

```
package com.pnt.common.propertyeditor;

import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import com.pnt.util.number.NumUtils;

public class IntegerPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {



//private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(IntegerPropertyEditor.class);





public void setValue(Object value) {

    if (value==null) {
        super.setValue(null);
    } 

    else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }

    else if (value instanceof String) {
        setValue(NumUtils.stringToInteger((String)value));
    }

    else {
        super.setValue(NumUtils.stringToInteger(value.toString()));
    }       
}


public void setAsText(String text) {
    setValue(NumUtils.stringToInteger(text.replaceAll(" ", "")));
}


public String getAsText() {
    Integer value = (Integer)getValue();
    if (value != null){ 
        String t = value.toString();
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = t.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (k % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
                t = t.substring(0, i) + " " + t.substring(i);
            k++;
        }
        return t;

    } 
    else 
        return "";
}
}
```

And you have to register it in the controller's initBinder() method:

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder ){
    try {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, "ssnField", new IntegerPropertyEditor());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Where "ssnField" is the name of the field.

Now all you have to do is tweak the PropertyEditor to match your format.

Comment: When editing the message, please check the right column, the message formatting rules are there. Please check the editor toolbar as well, it has tooltips. Finally please check the preview area below the editor, it shows how the message will end up.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`fmt:substring`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)